# equivalence relation and quotient set problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ and $S$ be equivalence relations on X so that $X/R$=$X/S$, prove that $R=S$ how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$; then $[x]_R=[y]_R$, where $[x]_R\in X/R$ is the $R$-equivalence class of $x$. By hypothesis $[x]_R=[x]_S$ and $[y]_R=[y]_S$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I think that $\;[x]_R=[x]_S\;$ is precisely what the OP needs to prove. So far we only know, if I understood correctly the question, that $\;[x]_R=[y]_S\;$ for some $\;y\in X\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio: Possibly; it depends on whether it’s already been shown that $[x]_R$ is the member of $X/R$ containing $x$, and I’d expect this to have been shown very early in the discussion of quotients.

Comment: thanks a lot Brian!! I can finish it! :D

Comment: @David: You’re welcome! (Do take note of the comment by DonAntonio and my answer; that may affect just how much detail you need to provide.)